# Facebook ios sdk language

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm using the latest version of the Facebook ios sdk and the language in the dialog is defaulting to Turkish. I'm using it Australia. When I go the facebook.com in Safari on my iPod it is in English. My brother said it has also happened in other apps. How would I fix this? is the a way to set the language to English by default?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the Facebook SDK for ios automatically detects the default language of your ipod application, which in this case is turkish. Try starting a test application which is only in english and you will find that the facebook dialogs turn into english as well.